# Unable to show error message from Angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm facing a couple of trivial issues with AngularJS:

Issue 1:
Plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/OpsgSwyaO0uzFtfuyggv?p=info shows an attempt to use Angular's directive to validate an input field and show error message. The ng-show does not seem to work.

Is this issue related to this bug?
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2500

From app.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.directive('mytag',function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,        
        templateUrl: 'inputwidget.html',
        require: '^form',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, formCtrl) {
        },
        scope: {
            controlname: '@nameattribute',
            controltype: '@typeattribute',
            controllabel: '@labelattribute',
            controlmodel: '=modelattribute',
            controlerror: '@errorattribute',
        },
        controller: function($scope) {                  
        }
    };
});

app.controller('ParentCtrl', function($scope){ 
});
```

The directive template code:

```
<div ng-transclude>
    <p>{{controllabel}}</p>
    <input type="{{controltype}}" name="{{controlname}}" ng-model="controlmodel"/>
    <div ng-show="form.controlname.$invalid">{{controlerror}}</div>
</div>
```

Issue 2:
With Angular 1.0.2 (the version of an original plunker I looked at and used above), I was able to execute this code (with said Issue #1); 
However, I'm not able to run it with the latest Angular 1.2.28. What is wrong with the code?

Please help!